# Entity Framework Code First: Skip Initial Model Discovery

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've been using the [Ignore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679542(v=vs.113).aspx) method to ignore entities that EF tries to map on my DB against my will. The doc states:

> *This is used to remove types from the model that were added by convention during **initial model discovery***

Now I find myself doing this for way too many entities in my model. Is there any way to tell EF I'm going to manually map the entire model or just skip the initial discovery?

Comment: I just found about the Conventions property of DbModelBuilder. Maybe there's something to be done with this?

Comment: I don't suppose you figured anything out with this? I just went through the list of default Conventions and didn't see one for general Discovery.

Comment: Not a total solution but if it helps at all we ended up restructuring our entities/contexts to a context per project. that way a context would only be in a project with the entities it uses. Then for entity inheritance we had to create a base project. Basically we used lots of projects to create scope for the initial model discovery.

Comment: Outch! One thing I may share though is that we now use EntityTypeConfiguration<> objects to configure our context. Instead of having one huge filthy OnModelCreating method, we create many cleaner small configuration objects which could be different depending on the project we use. My plan is to keep a common context project among solutions, and have one config objects project for each of them, which, thinking of it, finally resembles what you ended up doing...

Comment: As a side note, a search on conventions lead me to this link which looks interresting: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Conventions